# Withdrawing funds from contract to Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

Currently i am having issues withdrawing funds from a smart contract to gnosis. We followed the option 1 step from this guide: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40813-why-can-t-i-transfer-eth-from-a-contract-into-a-safe

but we are getting this error https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa0cd327f345c07ad4eb6bc8142d6130c8196f3521048c949a3498adeb4c7ae62

This is our implementation of our code: [image]

What did we do wrong? Why can't I withdraw funds to my gnosis via smart contract withdrawfunds function?

Comment: You don't need the second entry in your access list. You should remove it. You can access a successful simulation here: https://www.tdly.co/shared/simulation/0e0af30d-7843-44f3-98df-5de3071ae81b

Answer (score 0):

Well on tenderly simulator it also shows you are out of gas [image]